# How can I store data in a lookup in a type safe way?

Tags: java, data-structures, compiler-errors

Suppose I have a data structure like this:

`Map<DataType, Object> myMapLikeObject;`

```
public enum DataType {
    TRANSPARENT, PASSABLE, PASSAGE_COST; 
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to associate each enum constant with a data type like this:

```
public enum DataType {
    TRANSPARENT(Boolean.class),
    PASSABLE(Boolean.class),
    PASSAGE_COST(Integer.class); 
}
```

so if I try to `myMap.put(DataType.TRANSPARENT, "someStuff");` I can validate the input and throw an exception because it is not a `Boolean`. This works so far but it leads to runtime errors.

How can I write code that will result in a compile-time error with calls like this:
`myMap.put(DataType.TRANSPARENT, "someStuff");` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never tried a generic enum but I assume you can do this:

```
public enum DataType<T> {
    TRANSPARENT<Boolean>(Boolean.class),
    PASSABLE<Boolean>(Boolean.class),
    PASSAGE_COST<Integer>(Integer.class);

    private Class<T> type;

    private DataType<T>(Class<T> type) { this.type = type; }

    public Class<T> getType() { return type; }
}

public class DataTypeMap {
    private Map<DataType<?>, Object> map = new HashMap<DataType<?>, Object>();

    public <T> void put(DataType<T> dataType, T value) {
        map.put(dataType, value);
    }

    public <T> T get(DataType<T> dataType) {
        Object value = map.get(dataType);
        return dataType.getType().cast(value);
    }
}

public void someMethod() {
    DataTypeMap  map = new DataTypeMap();
    map.put(DataType.TRANSPARENT, true);
    map.put(DataType.PASSAGE_COST, 12345);
    map.put(DataType.PASSAGE_COST, "some string"); // compile error

    boolean flag = map.get(DataType.TRANSPARENT);
    int number = map.get(DataType.PASSAGE_COST);
    String string = map.get(DataType.PASSAGE_COST); // compile error
}
```

Answer (score -2):

A java MAP cannot contain duplicate keys. Therefore, when you try to put in a second item (key) into the map with the same type of TRANSPARENT, it will crash. I think you need a different type of approach (or different type of collection).

Although I don't really have enough information about what you are trying to accomplish to make suggestions, this might give you some ideas:

Create a new wrapper object that stores in it someStuff and the datatype. 
Example: create MyWrapper class that will have a constructor as follows: 
MyWrapper(DataType.TRANSPARENT, "someStuff");

Now you can use this:
Map myMapLikeObject;

Where String is some unique short phrase that describes the item 'someStuff'.